# Three.js canvas texture drawImage is black

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas

https://codepen.io/matelich/pen/PyRZeb

Trying to draw a white semi-transparent image to a transparent canvas / material. It's working fine, except its drawing as a black semi-transparent image.

```
function doPaintPoint (_x, _y) {
  var image3 = mesh.material.map.image;
  var ctx = image3.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(brushy, _x, _y);
  mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
  mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't your light behind your object? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxLboo

Comment: Oh my goodness, totally didn't occur to me. Thanks, @Kaiido!

Comment: @Kaiido if you want to write an answer that would be great. To close voter, I can see why this might not seem like an on-topic item, but I did try a number of other routes including moving the camera (but forgot to doubleside it) and to a 3d novice that's not the first thing that would come to mind. It just looked like the image was drawing black.

Comment: Ah... hum, I am the close-voter. I have to admit you've got a point it could maybe help someone else. I still don't feel good answering it though, so feel free to do it yourself.